# JavaFX graph with dynamic data entry

Tags: javafx

I am trying to code a graph that plots a curve based on an equation. The goal is to allow the user to enter as many (editable) numeric values as they would like in a GUI that would then plot the graph on the same scene. 
I am currently using multiple TextField() and looking into using a table view but it does not seem to be the answer.

Is there another possibility other then TextFields or table view that would allow the user to enter possibly unlimited amounts of data?

Answer (score 0):

Try a ScatterChart. You have to define the axes and the collection of value-pairs (usually done in an ObservableList).